# System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations version reference issue on Schema

Tags: c#, entity-framework, silverlight

I am working with an application that uses System.CodeDom.Compiler to generate Silverlight client DLL's for use in referencing entity framework entities.  My machine generates errors during the compilation process.  It is not finding System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.  This is not a  .net v4 for construct.  My machine we had upgraded to Silverlight 5 and discovered an incompatability with Silverlight 5 and had to return to Silverlight 4.  Other machines that were never attempted to upgrade to Silverlight 5 do not exhibit this issue.  The code explicitley includes a reference to  System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations when certain dataannotations are required.  I have not been able to expunge this dependency to a version of the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace that appears to be more advanced than my machine should have.  I can not move forward in version as I must remain compatable with an automated build process that distributes the results of my work to clients.  If I change the reference systax to work for me it will fail for everyone else.  I need ideas as to how to identify the source of this so that I can eliminate it.  The references within my project show correct versions, but since this compilation is done on the fly outside of my solution I do not know how I can verify the version used in the application generated compilation done later.  I have trapped the error at the time it occurs, but that is not helpful, as it is providing a list of the references by name at compile time and I do not know how it resolves to the particular dll's to use at that time, and it does not appear to be finding the one I think it should or it would not be referencing the .schema namespace.  Something I do not have a handle on is forcing in this reference.  I think this means I have something on my machine using an entity framework reference later than v4.3 but I think my machine has only v4.I am looking for thoughts on how I can track this down.

I have done many generic searches on this problem, finding many references to this particular error, some of which are on this site, that indicate I need to be looking for a problem with the versions of the DLL's, but I am not sure where the compilation is pulling the dll's from and the ones I have checked appear to be the correct version for the namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations so I think my problem must be being picked up from something else.

There are 2 not specifically Silverlight 4 assemblies listed as inputs to the compiler.  My two source files do not cause the reference, so I think if must come from one of these.

> ...\bin\RIAServices\v1.0\Libraries\Silverlight\System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.dll
>   ...\bin\RIAServices\v1.0\Libraries\Silverlight\System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.Web.dll

The actual error generated is:

> The type or namespace name 'Schema' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?) with an additional tage of: error CS0234.

Most posted solutions involve an upgrade to a later version of Dot Net and/or Entity Framework and those are not available to me.

I am no expert on Entity Framework or RIA Services and may be overlooking something fundamental.